# how do i determine if the script is being loaded in Ajax Using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax

How do i determine if the script is being loaded in Ajax using jQuery, for example i am using the following jQuery/AJAX.

```
$('#select-countries').change(function(){
    var countryId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'process.php',
        data: 'countryId='+countryId,
        success: function(states){
            if(states == 'null') {
                $('#select-states-container').html(emptyState);
            } else if(states == '0') {
                $('#select-states-container').html(chooseState);
            } else {
                $('#select-states-container').html(states);
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Now depending upon the loading state i want to display a message or display a loading gif, i would like to know if there are ajax states like on-loading, on-complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is to pop up a loading dialog before the ajax call and then use ajax#complete() to remove it or change the mssage:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'process.php',
    data: 'countryId='+countryId,
    beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings) {
       // show the awesome dialog
    },
    complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
       // remove the awesome dialog
    },
    error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       // post the not so awesome message in the awesome dialog
    },
    success: function(states){
        if(states == 'null') {
            $('#select-states-container').html(emptyState);
        } else if(states == '0') {
            $('#select-states-container').html(chooseState);
        } else {
            $('#select-states-container').html(states);
        } 
        // change the message in the awesome dialog???
    }
});
```

Comment: what are those two arguments jqXHR and settings in beforeSend ?

Comment: @Ibrahim: Couldn't be bothered to read the documentation, even if your life depended on it, apparently. Here you go: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings

Comment: @ibrahim you don't HAVE to have them, I included them for completeness but if you leave them off, beforeSend (and others) will work just fine.  Read the documentation links that Piskvor provided to know if you need them or not.

Answer (score 2):

From http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ :

> beforeSend(jqXHR, settings)
>   A pre-request callback function
>
> error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
>   A function to be called if the request fails
>
> success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
>   A function to be called if the request succeeds.
>
> complete(jqXHR, textStatus)
>   A function to be called when the request finishes (after success and error callbacks are executed).

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url:  'process.php',
    data: 'countryId='+countryId,
    beforeSend: function() {
        your_loading_function();
    },
    success: function(states){
        if(states == 'null') {
            $('#select-states-container').html(emptyState);
        } else if(states == '0') {
            $('#select-states-container').html(chooseState);
        } else {
            $('#select-states-container').html(states);
        }   
    },
    complete: function() {
        clear_your_loading_message();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#select-countries').change(function(){
    var countryId = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  'process.php',
        data: 'countryId='+countryId,
        beforeSend(jqXHR, settings) {
            // Here is your 'loading' state
            $('#select-states-container').html('Loading...');
        },
        complete: function(jqHXR, status) {
            // Here is your complete state, unbiased of success or fail
            alert('Ajax call completed');
        },
        error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Here is your complete state with error
            $('#select-states-container').html(textStatus + ' -- ' + errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(states){
            if(states == 'null') {
                $('#select-states-container').html(emptyState);
            } else if(states == '0') {
                $('#select-states-container').html(chooseState);
            } else {
                $('#select-states-container').html(states);
            }   
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: well i am searching for loading, and i don't see that in your code :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use any of the global ajax events that meet your needs here, you're probably after [$.ajaxComplete()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) or [$.ajaxSuccess()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) for completion and [$.ajaxStart()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) for initiation.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use ajaxStart, ajaxSend and ajaxStop to register a handler in an ajax request

```
$('#selected-countries').ajaxStop(function() {
  //do something....
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/